# Computing in-place with dask

Tags: dask

### Short version

I have a dask array whose graph is ultimately based on a bunch of numpy arrays at the bottom, and which applies elementwise operations to them. Is it safe to use `da.store` to compute the array and store the results back into the original backup numpy arrays, making the whole thing an in-place operation?

If you're thinking "you're using dask wrong" then see the long version below for why I feel the need to do this.

### Long version

I'm using dask for an application where the original data is sourced from in-memory numpy arrays that contain data collected from a scientific instrument. The goal is to fill most of the RAM (say 75%+) with the original data, which means that there isn't enough to make an in-memory copy. That makes it semantically a bit like an out-of-core problem, in that any derived value can only be realised in memory in chunks rather than all at once.

Dask is well-suited to this, except for one wrinkle. I'm simplifying a lot, but on most of the data (call it X), we need to apply an element-wise operation `f`, compute some summary statistics `s(f(X))`, and use that to compute another result over the data, say `t(s(f(X)), f(X))`. While all the functions are dask-friendly (can be done on a per-chunk basis), trying to simply run this dask graph would cause `f(X)` to all be held in memory at once because the chunks are all needed for the second pass. An alternative is to explicitly compute `s` before asking for `t` (as suggested by https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/874), and thus pay to compute `f(X)` twice, but it's a somewhat expensive operation so I'd like to avoid that.

However, once `f` has been applied, the original data are no longer needed.  So I'd like to run `da.store(f(X))` and have it store the results in the original backing numpy arrays. Technically I think I know how to set that up, and as long as I can be sure that each piece of data is fully consumed before it is overwritten then there are no race conditions, but I'm worried that I may be breaking an API contract by changing back data underneath dask and that it might go wrong in some way. Is there any way to *guarantee* that it is safe?

One way I can immediately see this going wrong is if several of the input arrays have the same contents and hence get given the same name in dask, causing them to the unified in the graph. I'm using `name=False` in `da.from_array` though, so that shouldn't be an issue.